# MySQL Full Outer Join Workaround

Tags: mysql

Query Definition:

Show me all the students and all the teachers and list together those who have the same first name.

I want include students and teachers with same FirstName.

It doesn't matter if they are repeated more than once.As Each Student,Teacher will have unique StudentID,StaffID respectively.

Data:

```
Student Table:
```

```
StudFirstName 
   David
   John
```

Staff Table:

```
StfFirstName 
  David
  Arnold
```

**Expected Result:
David**

I have searched on the internet for **Mysql Full Outer Join Workaround**

**I have found below two techniques.**

**Technique 1: Using Union All:**

```
Select Students.StudFirstName
from Students
Left Outer Join Staff
On Students.StudFirstName = Staff.StfFirstName

Union all 

Select Students.StudFirstName 
from Students
Right Outer Join Staff
On Students.StudFirstName = Staff.StfFirstName

where Staff.StfFirstName is null;
```

**Technique 2:Using Union:**

```
Select Students.StudFirstName
from Students
Left Outer Join Staff
On Students.StudFirstName = Staff.StfFirstName

Union 

Select Students.StudFirstName 
from Students
Right Outer Join Staff
On Students.StudFirstName = Staff.StfFirstName;
```

**Technique 3: But I got Expected Results by using 
Query 3:**

```
Select Students.StudFirstName
from Students,Staff
where Students.StudFirstName = Staff.StfFirstName;
```

**My Question:**

**How can i get the same result by using Technique 1 & 2 ?**

**What is the Difference between Technique 1,2 and 3 if all of them give same results?
Which Technique should be used when?**

Comment: The best way, when the two tables are not linked is the Query 3. But you have to add a `DISTINCT` limiter.

Comment: Have you seen how the three behave if you were to have another David as staff, and another David as a student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first two are... complicated for what you want (or seem to want).

I think it's just that either the "request" is bad formulated, or the result is not what you show.

> Show me all the students and all the teachers and list together those
>   who have the same first name

Should be, with the "wanted" result (if you just want "David", you certainly don't want "All the students and all the teachers")

> Show me common firstNames between Students and Teachers.

Then your third query would be fine, just rewritten in a more appropriated syntax, to

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.StudFirstName
FROM Students stu
INNER JOIN Staff sta
  ON stu.StudFirstName = sta.StfFirstName;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT stu.StudFirstName
FROM Students stu
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM Staff sta
              WHERE stu.StudFirstName = sta.StfFirstName);
```

**EDIT**
use of DISTINCT to avoid to have 3 David... if you have 3 David in Students and just wanna retrieve "one" David. Not clear with your question. Not clear, also : what sould be retrieved if you have 3 David in Staff table...

Comment: My Expected Result is:David, thats it.I was confused by Technique 1 and 2 i saw on the internet.In what case Technique 1 & 2 can be used

Comment: @user2144699 UNION will remove duplicate records. UNION ALL will not. If you have 2 David in Students (and 1 in Staff), and want only 1 David as result, your second query (and my answers) will work. 1 and 3 won't.

Answer (score 0):

To know what `Union` and `Union ALL` does

**[Refer this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/974786/4)**

**[To get result by Technique 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f57/1)**

I really doubt whether you can achieve the **same result** from **Technique 1**.

And to get Distinct Result please edit your **3rd Query** like this:

```
Select distinct Students.StudFirstName
from Students,Staff
where Students.StudFirstName = Staff.StfFirstName;
```

Taking MySQL into Considertaion